# Make the footer stick to the bottom but the hight is dependent of an object

Tags: html, css, sticky-footer

so recently I'm working on a webpage to sell clothing, somehow I have problems in positioning my footer. At the moment the Footer looks like this. https://i.stack.imgur.com/3zQt0.png
I want to stick the line to the bottom, which means, lookbook, shop, about and the line sticks with a bit of space to the bottom and if u scroll down the rest of the footer is revelead. It would look like this then: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VzGJi.png
I don't want to work with space or anything since I want to have my website dynamic and responsive, means It looks at the macbook with 13' as same as on Windows on a 27' monitor. Anyways hope anyone of you guys can help me since I want to drop soon.
My code looks like this and is currently fixed to the bottom of the page.

```
.footer{
width: 100%                                                                                                         
position: fixed
left: 0
height: 282px
bottom: 0
background:#F7F7F0
}
```

Greets

Comment: try by setting a `min-height`,  in pc if there is less the space will be added, in mobile normally will be more height so is not visible that property,

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: Well I will try the min-height, but currently, what happens if I have a long text like terms & conditions. I want to display it at the very bottom of the page. As my footer is global there's only the way to hard code this for specific websites. I want to do this dinamicly

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

So I tried flexbox, smh I'm not able to use flexbox in elementor. Second point is, that I tried setting the height to fit to the screen, also using the min-height like Anas wrote, still I can only scroll the footer and not the footer when scrolling the page. Hope to get help asap.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Comments like this should be added to the comment section by clicking [Add a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72729404/make-the-footer-stick-to-the-bottom-but-the-hight-is-dependent-of-an-object/72733357#). Please post your comment there and delete this, as this is not an answer to the question.